# Exploit agains metasploit system

Tags: metasploit

I'm working on an assignment using `Kali Linux` to exploit against the `Metasploit` system. A question in regards to my assignment is:

What application did it (the exploit I used) exploit on `Metasploit`?

I used `samba/usermap_script`.

I don't know how to tell which application was exploited.

Answer (score 1):

According to this link:

https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/multi/samba/usermap_script

"This module exploits a command execution vulnerability in Samba versions 3.0.20 through 3.0.25rc3"

So it's exploiting an application on Linux called "Samba".